# How many binary equivalences are there on a $3$ element set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Given the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$

How many different binary equivalence relations can be formed?

Can I list all of them?

Furthermore, how will this answer change as I add more elements to the set?

Comment: Google "Bell numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that every equivalence relation on a set defines a partition, and vice versa.  So look at ways to break up $\{1,2,3\}$ into nonempty pieces.  $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ is one.  But then you have $\{\{2\},\{1,3\}\}$ and $\{\{3\},\{1,2\}\}$...

Comment: Can we not answer no-context questions. Please?

Comment: @DonThousand, could you stop being so repressive?

Comment: @DonThousand, despite of a bunch of SE-Mathematics (pseudo)axioms, let's enjoy doing mathematics in varied ways. Let's avoid meta-comments under mathematical questions. (Well, my comment was even meta-meta-comment, oops, I'll go back to mathematics on whatever level).

Comment: About partitions, @Antonymous, remember to include the two trivial (extreme) partitions (these two would be one in a trivial case).

Comment: A good answer using a smart idea (+1).